# Tcl string double quote

Tags: string, tcl

I write this code in tcl script

```
set setting "-D key=value "
append setting "-D key2=value2"

catch {exec icv -vue $setting -c $cell_name -i $gds_file $::RULE_SET } err
puts "error == $err"
```

above line execute like this.........

```
icv -vue "-D key=value -D key2=value2" -c top -i /re/xyz/abc.gds /re/xyz/ab.rs
```

I want to remove double quote from output command ....?
I want output like this................

```
icv -vue -D key=value -D key2=value2 -c top -i /re/xyz/abc.gds /re/xyz/ab.rs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Tcl8.5 or above, you can argument expansion operator `{*}`, as

```
catch {exec icv -vue {*}$setting -c $cell_name -i $gds_file $::RULE_SET } err
```

If you are using Tcl8.4 or below, then you can use `eval` command

```
catch {eval exec icv -vue $setting -c $cell_name -i $gds_file $::RULE_SET } err
```